# FullSimplify fails with simple assumptions

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

I have a list of relations of the form

```
x[1] x[2] + y[1] y[2] - z[1] z[2] == 0
```

and I want Mathematica to simplify certain expressions using these relations.
I have been using `FullSimplify` with assumptions, and I have found that it doesn't work occasionally. For example:

```
FullSimplify[(a b - e f)/c, Assumptions -> {a b + c d - e f == 0}]
```

works just fine, and gives the correct answer `-d`, but for some reason

```
FullSimplify[(c d - e f)/a, Assumptions -> {a b + c d - e f == 0}]
```

returns `(c d - e f)/a`.
Any idea why this happens and how to make sure that Mathematica recognizes the second example as `-b`?

Comment: I'd say that `Reduce` is more appropriate for this sort of thing. For example: `Reduce[(c d - e f)/a == y && a b + c d - e f == 0]`

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to act another way around. For example, below I use the equation `a b + c d - e f == 0` to express one or another parameter in order to then substitute it to the expression under simplification:

```
sol1 = Solve[a b + c d - e f == 0, c][[1, 1]]
sol2 = Solve[a b + c d - e f == 0, a][[1, 1]]
sol3 = Solve[a b + c d - e f == 0, d][[1, 1]]

(*  c -> (-a b + e f)/d

a -> (-c d + e f)/b

d -> (-a b + e f)/c   *)
```

Then let us substitute successively these three solutions into the expression under simplification:

```
Simplify[(c d - e f)/a /. sol1]
Simplify[(c d - e f)/a /. sol2]
Simplify[(c d - e f)/a /. sol3]


(*  -b

-b

-b  *)
```

Each of these ways is one step longer than your approach with the equation, but they are safer.

As a minor note: `FullSimplify` is not necessary here. `Simplify` is enough.

Have fun!